# How can I dynamically enable/disable logging for a specific osgi bundle?

Tags: logging, osgi, bundle

How can I dynamically enable/disable logging for a specific osgi bundle?

A method in the Bundle class where I can set/get a boolean value would be nice, but there's no such method.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best bet may be to use log levels with log4j/pax logging. If bundle A is logging using log4j with pax-logging and all of its logging is in package com.bundle.a, then you can turn off logging for that package using ConfigAdmin and standard log4j log level settings.

https://ops4j1.jira.com/wiki/display/paxlogging/Configuration

Answer (score 0):

In OSGi, logging is a service. There is no standard for the kind of functionality you want and there are as far as I know no implementations that provide this feature. Strange, because it should be quite easy to add such a feature.